# Returning Future<Object> instead of Object

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand why IDE is not complaining about changing the type from Object to Future in this function:

```
class PromotionRepository implements IPromotionRepository {
  final CollectionReference collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('promotions');

  Future<List<Promotion>> getAllPromotions() async {
    QuerySnapshot query = await collection.get();
    List<Promotion> promotions =
        query.docs.map((doc) => Promotion.fromFirestore(doc)).toList();
    return promotions;
  }
}
```

In this case I am returning `List<Promotion>`, not the `Future<List<Promotion>`, but in method signature I have returning type defined as `Feature...`

There is no difference if I change to just `List<Promotion>`. It works the same way in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return `List<Promotion>` but inside async method. Everything returned in async methods is a [`Future`](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#what-is-a-future).

You even declared type before name of the method.

Here you have few simple samples. Notice, that everywhere `true` is returned, but in different types of methods.

```dart
void main() {
  print(streamTest().runtimeType); // result: Stream<bool>
  print(asyncTest().runtimeType); // result: Future<bool>
  print(syncTest().runtimeType); // esult bool
}

Stream<bool> streamTest() async* {
  yield true;
}

Future<bool> asyncTest() async => true;

bool syncTest() => true;
```